# Return a boolean mask for a Pandas index wrt a subset of the index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

`df = pd.DataFrame(index=["a", "b", "c"], data={"col": [1, 2, 3]})`

And a subset of the indexes: `s = ["a", "b"]`

I would like to form the boolean mask so I can change the values of row "a" and "b" only, like so:

`df.loc[m, "col"]  = [10, 11]`

Is there a neat way to do this?

Comment: seems like just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If list of assigned values is same like list of indexes use:

```
df.loc[s, "col"]  = [10, 11]
print (df)
   col
a   10
b   11
c    3
```

If use boolean mask by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) and order of list is different like indices get different ouput:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=["a", "b", "c"], data={"col": [1, 2, 3]})
#swapped order
s = ["b", "a"]


m = df.index.isin(s)
df.loc[m, "col"]  = [10, 11]
print (df)
   col
a   10
b   11
c    3

df.loc[s, "col"]  = [10, 11]
print (df)
   col
a   11
b   10
c    3
```